# DDD, Aggregate root без ORM, как сохранять?

Tags: java, c#, entity-framework, dapper, ddd

```
public class Order
{
   List<OrderItem> Items {get; private set;}

   public AddItem(OrderItem item)
   {
       //логика добавления

       items.Add(item);
   }
}
```

Следуя методологии DDD вся логика домена находится внутри домена и не выносится в отдельные сервисы. Вопрос в том как сохранять изменения корня агрегации **не используя ORM**, ну или используя microOrm - Dapper. Как делаете вы?

Comment: Слишком много умных слов - спрашивая таким языком, вы ответ долго будете получать. Ну и вопрос - почему же таки `не используя ORM` - чем орм вам не угодил? Что такое microOrm - такой технологии не слышал, и чем же он в корне отличается от ORM, что ORM прямо таки не хочется использовать?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону CQRS (разделение ответственности на команды и запросы). Когда за изменение данных будут отвечать отдельные команды, то не важно, что вы используете для DAL, так как реализация команды фактически скрыта. В вышем случае для сохранения Order, вы сможете написать реализацию команды Save так как посчитаете нужным, не привязываясь к ORM.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, понятно что будет например команда AddItemToOrderCommand, внутри мы достанем Order, создадим Item положив его в Order. Вот и вопрос, как после всех манипуляций сохранить Order со всеми изменениями. Понятно что можно просто положиить item чисто sql insert. Вопрос как сделать, как делают отцы) по феншую) best practics

Comment: @coder Если вы делаете команду AddItemToOrderCommand, то она и будет сохранять Order, либо делаете generic команду SaveCommand<>, которая будет заниматься сохранением

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В соответствии с принципами DDD, хранением сущностей ведают хранилища, они же *репозитории*, которые позволяют читать и писать *агрегаты*. В данном случае, репозиторий заказов должен уметь прочитать и записать агрегат *заказ*, включающий *позиции заказа*.

Поскольку способ хранения сущностей может измениться с большой долей вероятности, мы объявляем в предметной области не реализацию репозитория, а только интерфейс:

```
public interface IOrderRepository
{
    Order Create();

    Order ReadById(int id);

    void Update(Order order);

    void DeleteById(ind id);
}
```

Реализация этого интерфейса будет находится в *инфраструктурном слое приложения* (термин Эрика Эванса). Не в DDD этот слой называют *слоем доступа к данным*. В соответствии с принципом сокрытия данных, с инфраструктурного слоя нельзя добраться до внутренних данных сущности *Заказ*.

Пример: у сущности `Order` есть свойство `CreatedAt`, то есть *дата создания*. По правилам предметной области это свойство *только для чтения*, то есть имеет метод-геттер, но не имеет метода-сеттера. Когда *репозиторий заказов* загружает данные из базы, он должен установить значения всех свойств, в том числе и `CreatedAt`. Но он не может этого сделать, потому что не может изменить значение свойства только для чтения.

Похожая проблема описана в GoF, и там для её решения применяют паттерн *Memento* (*Хранитель*). Он позволяет сохранить состояние объекта и восстановить его впоследствии. В классической схеме состояние хранится в виде, недоступном для анализа и понимания, но нам нужно кое-что другое.

Если мы используем СУБД, мы хотим, чтобы состояние было в таком виде, который удобно хранить в СУБД. Для этого мы вводим DTO-объекты для наших сущностей. Эти объекты также находятся в слое домена, поскольку являются частью его интерфейса для инфраструктурного уровня.

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public OrderItemDto[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItemDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public decimal Count { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
     private readonly OrderDto dto;
     private readonly List<OrderItem> items;

     public int Id { get { return dto.Id; } }

     public DateTime CreatedAt { get { return dto.CreatedAt; } }

     public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItem> Items { . . . }

     internal Order(OrderDto dto)
     {
         this.dto = dto;

         items = new List<OrderItem>();
         foreach (var orderItemDto in dto.Items)
             items.Add(new OrderItem(orderItemDto));
     }

     public void AddItem(Product product, decimal count)
     {
         var itemDto = new OrderItemDto
         {
             Id = 0,
             OrderId = this.Id,
             ProductId = product.Id,
             Count = count,
             Amount = product.Price * count
         };

         dto.Items.Add(itemDto);

         var item = new OrderItem(itemDto);
         items.Add(item);
     }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    internal OrderItem(OrderItemDto dto)
    {
        . . .
    }

    . . .
}
```

В таком виде, репозиторий загружает данные из базы, преобразует их в DTO-объект и затем из DTO-объекта создает объект предметной области. Либо он получает сущность предметной области, преобразует её в DTO-объект, и сохраняет его.

```
public class AdoOrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private readonly SqlConnection connection;

    public AdoOrderRepository(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public Order ReadById(int id)
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            // загружаем данные заказа включая агрегированные позиции
            // в объект OrderDto
            OrderDto orderDto = . . .;

            // волшебным образом преобразуем OrderDto в Order
            Order order = . . .;

            return order;
        }
    }

    public void Update(Order order)
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            // волшебным образом преобразуем Order в OrderDto
            OrderDto orderDto = . . .;

            // обновляем данные из OrderDto
            . . .
        }
    }
}
```

Зафиксирую ещё раз: слой предметной области описывает сущности предметной области (`Order`, `OrderItem`), отдельно он описывает интерфейсы репозиториев (`IOrderRepository`), которые нужно реализовать в инфраструктурном слое (`AdoOrderRepository`), и, наконец, он описывает DTO-объекты (`OrderDto`, `OrderItemDto`), которые содержат все поля, которые сущность (`Order`) хочет долговременно хранить. Сущности (`Order`) содержат логику и скрывают реализацию, DTO-объекты содержат только данные и никакой логики.

Реализации репозиториев умеют работать с DTO-объектами, в частности, могут послать запрос на чтение к базе и записать результаты в DTO-объект, поскольку DTO-объект очень прост. Но как они преобразуют DTO-объект в сущность, и обратно? В примере кода, который я привёл выше, я написал, что это происходит *волшебным образом*.

Пришло время разобраться, как именно. Сохранять и восстанавливать своё состояние могли бы сами объекты предметной области, такие, как `Order`. Но у них есть основная функция — это Заказы предметной области. Добавление второй функции нарушит принцип единственной ответственности. Нам нужен отдельный класс, который должен иметь доступ к состоянию сущности `Order`. Но один класс не должен знать детали реализации другого класса.

Кроме случая, когда этот класс вложенный.

```
public class Order
{
    private readonly OrderDto dto;

    private Order(OrderDto dto)
    {
        this.dto = dto;
    }

    . . .

    public static class DtoMapper
    {
        public static void Map(Order order, OrderDto orderDto)
        {
            . . .
        }

        public static void Map(OrderDto orderDto, Order order)
        {
            . . .
        }
    }
}
```

Внутренний класс описан, как публичный, поэтому реализации репозиториев на инфраструктурном уровне могут обращаться к нему.

При таком подходе неважно, как именно реализованы репозитории: через большой ORM вроде Entity Framework, через простой microORM Dapper, или через ADO.

Нужно внимательно обращаться с агрегированными объектами, такими, как коллекции
`OrderItem`/`OrderItemDto`. Внутри у нас коллекция `OrderItemDto`, снаружи `OrderItem`, и они должны соответствовать друг другу. Эта задача не очень сложная.

Наконец, я бы хотел проиллюстрировать различие между объектами предметной области и DTO, потому что иногда кажется, что между ними так много общего, что от DTO можно было бы и отказаться. Иногда общего действительно много, но иногда нет.

Если у нас есть сущность *пользователь*, у которой есть пароль, то, в предметной области она выглядит так:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; }

    public string Login { get; }

    bool ValidatePassword(string password);

    void ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword);
}
```

DTO-объект для неё выглядит кардинально по другому.

```
public class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

Как видим, DTO-объект открывает доступ к сырым данным, в данном случае к хешу пароля. Объект предметной области скрывает хеш не только для записи, но и для чтения, чтобы избежать возможных проблем с безопасностью. Он предоставляет методы `ValidatePassword` и `ChangePassword`, которые подсказывают нам сценарии использования объекта `User`.

Именно поэтому DTO-объекты и сущности предметной области, не смотря на некоторое дублирование полей, относятся к разным уровням и имеют разное назначения.

Есть несколько советов по тому, как проектировать DTO-объекты. В идеале их нужно делать такими, чтобы их можно было сразу использовать в Entity Framework, NHibernate или Dapper. Это означает, что вы можете использовать и *внешние ключи*, и *навигационные свойства*, и атрибуты вроде `[Key]`, `[TableName]` из пространства имён `System.Components.Annotations`. Это не обязательно, но упростит реализацию репозиториев. С другой стороны, лучше не ориентироваться на специфичные для конкретных ORM атрибуты и решения, такие как `[Index]`. Таким образом вы оставляете DTO-объекты непривязанными к конкретным ORM и можете быстро перейти от EF/SQL к MongoDB или Redis.

Наконец, после бесконечной теории, дам конкретный ответ на вопрос — как именно сохранять изменения корня агрегации, не используя ORM. Допишу метод `AdoOrderRepository.Update`:

```
public void Update(Order order)
{
    var orderDto = new OrderDto();
    Order.DtoMapper.Map(order, orderDto);

    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var orderDto = new OrderDto();
        Order.DtoMapper.Map(order, orderDto);

        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Orders] SET CreatedAt = @CreatedAt WHERE Id = @Id";
        // Поле CreatedAt только для чтения, так что я просто
        // иллюстрирую идею.
        command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedAt", orderDto.CreatedAt);
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", orderDto.Id);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.CommandText = "UPDATE [OrderItems] SET Count = @Count, Amount = @Amount WHERE Id = @Id";
        foreach (var item in dto.Items.Where(x => x.Id != 0))
        {
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.Add("@Count", item.Count);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Amount", item.Amount);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Id", item.Id);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        command.CommandText = "INSERT [OrderItems] (OrderId, ProductId, Count, Amount) VALUES (@OrderId, @ProductId, @Count, @Amount)";
        foreach (var item in dto.Items.Where(x => x.Id == 0))
        {
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.Add("@OrderId", item.OrderId);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", item.ProductId);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Count", item.Count);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Amount", item.Amount);

            item.Id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }

    Order.DtoMapper.Map(orderDto, order);
}
```

В соответствии с DDD мы должны сохранить не только корень агрегата, но и все агрегированные сущности, что мы в этом методе и делаем. Транзакцию создаем, чтобы обеспечить согласованность изменений. Код получился громоздкий, но простой. Чтобы избавиться от громоздкости, как раз можно задействовать Dapper.

Comment: спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, не совсем понял где добавляется новый ItemOrder. Сама идея с dto понятна а вот про добавление в базу нового item в существующем order, не совсем понял.

Comment: Реализации могут быть разные, я привожу одну из возможных, она близка к тому, как мы пишем код у себя в проекте. Новый `ItemOrder` добавляется в методе `Order.AddItem`, я его дописал немного, чтобы проиллюстрировать, что происходит. Также дописал метод `AdoOrderRepository.Update`, чтобы показать, что новые товарные позиции вставляются с помощью `INSERT`, а не `UPDATE`.

Comment: Марк спасибо еще раз, очень доходчивый ответ, еще интересует такой вопрос в вашей реализации, получается вы пробегаете по всей коллекции item и обновляете даже те которые не изменились, не слишком ли это накладно? или это просто для примера и используете другой способ?

Comment: Да, конечно, это только иллюстрация. В рабочем коде у нас EF, который мы немного допилили напильниками в самых медленных местах. При записи в базу обновляются только изменённые свойства. С другой стороны, это зависит от предметной области. В некоторых случаях обновления базы не настолько массовые, и можно сделать код проще, просто обновляя всё.

Comment: А нужно ли хранить ссылку на `OrderDto` в `Order`? Вроде бы достаточно восстановить свое состояние и "выбросить" дто.

Comment: @andreycha, Вы правы, хранить не обязательно. Мы разные способы пробовали, этот вариант показался самым простым, потому что конструктор объекта получается тривиальным. Но такой способ, конечно, не единственный.